# Snackbar overlays Admob banner ad

Tags: android, admob, android-snackbar

I have a snackbar which overlays the banner ad. It has a LENGTH_INDEFINITE because I have some functionality I need to complete after the snackbar is displayed.

Would this be considered a violation of the admob's banner policy described here - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en

### What I have tried to overcome this ?

I have created a constraintlayout as a parent with it's children being the banner ad and another constraintlayout with everything you see in the layout. I am rendering the snackbar on the child layout, yet it renders out of it's layout on to the parents bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor your Snackbar on the AdView, then it will be always displayed above the AdView.

Call below on your SnackBar before displaying it to the user.

```
setAnchorView(findViewById<AdView>(R.id.your_adview_id))
```

More details here:
[SnackBar Android](https://material.io/components/snackbars/android)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works exactly as expected.